# Can't get html elements connected to a certain tag using lxml

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I've created an xpath expression to reach `a` tag out of some html elements. The thing is I can't print it in the console.

What I wish to get is the concerning html elements connected to the tag `a` using lxml library.

This is my try:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

htmlcontent = """
<div class="post-taglist">
    <div class="grid">
        <a href="/questions/tagged/python"></a> 
    </div>
</div>
"""
root = fromstring(htmlcontent)
item = root.xpath("//*[@class='grid']/a")[0]
print(item)
```

The output I wanna get:

```
<a href="/questions/tagged/python"></a>
```

How can I do that? I googled using many search terms but could not find any direct answer to this question.

Comment: tag `a` is not opened properly.. it should be like: `<a href="/questions/tagged/python"></a>` correct it then check.

Comment: Edited to reflect the change but it still gives `<Element a at 0x1ff0480>` which I was having earlier as well @Amrendra Kumar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following, based on [docs](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#serialisation):

```
from lxml.html import fromstring, tostring

htmlcontent = """
<div class="post-taglist">
    <div class="grid">
        <a href="/questions/tagged/python"></a> 
    </div>
</div>
"""

root = fromstring(htmlcontent)
item = root.xpath("//*[@class='grid']/a")[0]

print(tostring(item).strip())
```

which results in:

```
<a href="/questions/tagged/python"></a>
```

Comment: so, ***fromstring*** alone was not sufficient enough to do the trick!!!. Thanks for your solution @Gasanov.

Comment: @asmitu , this is correct way to extract outerHTML, but you can use `tostring` from the same module: `from lxml.html import fromstring, tostring`  as `print(tostring(item))`

Comment: @Andersson Yep, you are right. I've updated answer accordingly.